# Primefaces with 3d Highchart error

Tags: jsf, primefaces, highcharts

In my Project I use Primefaces with 3d Highchart try to show result.That time I faces error in browser is a.graphic.out.add(c) type undefined Line number 750 in Highchart-3d.js.Highchart-2d support but 3d is not support.

Pass value in xhtml pagegenerate3DPieChartReport('piechartID',"maths,50:science,50);

**chart.js**

```
function generate3DPieChartReport(pieChartContainerDivId, chartData, report)
{

    pieChartContainerId = pieChartContainerDivId;
    pieChartData = chartData;
    percentageSymbol = "";
    pieChartReport = report;
    create3DPieChart();
}
function create3DPieChart()
{
    var units = {
        title: ''
    };
    var optionsPie = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: pieChartContainerId,
            defaultSeriesType: 'pie',
            backgroundColor:'none',
            options3d: {
                enabled: true,
                alpha: 65
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>' + this.point.name + '</b>: ' + this.y + ' ' + units.title;
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                innerSize: 55,
                depth: 25,
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                events: {
                    click: function(e) {
                        showDetails(e);
                    }
                },
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>' + this.point.name + '</b>: ' + this.y + percentageSymbol;
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: []
    };
    Highcharts.setOptions({
        colors: ['#058DC7', '#50B432', '#ED561B', '#DDDF00', '#24CBE5', '#64E572', '#FF9655', '#FFF263', '#6AF9C4']
    });
    var seriesPie = {
        data: []
    };
    var seriesPieItem = new Array();
    var chartSliceTokens = pieChartData.split(":");

    for (var i = 0; i < chartSliceTokens.length; i++)
    {
        var sliceValue = chartSliceTokens[i];
        var sliceIndivdualToken = sliceValue.split(",");

        var sliceName = "";
        var sliceVal = "";
        seriesPieItem = new Array();

        for (var j = 0; j < sliceIndivdualToken.length; j++)
        {
            if (j == 0)
            {
                sliceName = sliceIndivdualToken[j];
            }
            if (j == 1)
            {
                sliceVal = sliceIndivdualToken[j];
            }

            if (sliceName != "" && sliceVal != "")
            {
                seriesPieItem.push(sliceName);
                seriesPieItem.push(parseFloat(sliceVal));
                seriesPie.data.push(seriesPieItem);
            }
        }
    }
    optionsPie.series.push(seriesPie);
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(optionsPie);
}
```

Comment: Some code would be helpful.

Comment: I am unable to recreate the problem - http://jsfiddle.net/roLekgbt/. Could you post a live demo, e.g. in JSFiddle?

Comment: Thank You Now It's work fine .Now  Highchart.com label has been shown in chart .Then how to hide it.  jsfiddle.net/roLekgbt also  label has be show.